# Storyboard instantiateWithIdentifier cause crash on iOS 13

Tags: uiviewcontroller, storyboard, xcode11, ios13

Testing my app in **Xcode 11 (beta)** for **iOS-13 (beta)** updates and I'm getting crash on when I tried to instantiate viewController from storyboard.

In previous versions its working fine with the following code:

```
XYZController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IDENTIFIER"];
```

Now for iOS 13 Apple introduces new method i.e.

```
XYZController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IDENTIFIER" creator:^__Kindof UIViewController *__Nullable(NSCoder *_Nonnull coder){
    return [XYZController alloc] initWithCoder:coder];
}];
```

Executing both method in iOS-13 cause crash. While crash shows somewhere else.

Here is my crash report.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
>   '' returned nil from -traitCollection, which
>   is not allowed.

Comment: test with an empty (new) view controller...do you override traitCollection method?

Comment: no i didn't override any method

Comment: Does an empty view controller crash?

Comment: I've got the same issue. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: Temporary Solution

I also have face this issue and there are two temporary fixes I have found. First is to create object/property of the controller that need to be instantiate and `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` in your controllers's `viewDidLoad`. App will not crash.

Second is to instantiate controller in `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())`. These both tricks worked for me.